# Recursive function with block in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've got a function with completion block, and which in some cases calls itself recursively until has the expected result.

I'm getting errors in release, probably because it has different memory management in release.

Anyway I'm asking what should I do to make it work in release as in debug.

I've found some links about declaring a block variable weak, and another one strong, and then assign the block to both of them. However I'm in difficulty to understand well how to apply it to my code.

Here's the code:

```
-(void) getBitmapFromXObject: (OCPdfXObject *) xobj completion:(void(^)(NSData * data))completion{
    __block BOOL hasAlreadyCompleted = false;
        
    if (xobj.type == OCPdfXObjectType_Form) {
        OCPdfXObjectForm * formxboj = (OCPdfXObjectForm *)xobj;
        OCPdfDictionary * res = formxboj.resources.xObject;
        if (res != nil) {
            for (CBKeyValuePair * key in res) {
                OCPdfXObject* childXObjc = [OCPdfXObject createFromObject:key.value];
                if (!childXObjc) {
                    continue;
                }
                [self getBitmapFromXObject:childXObjc completion:^(NSData *data) {
                    if (data != nil) {
                        hasAlreadyCompleted = true;
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }
    if (xobj.type == OCPdfXObjectType_Image) {
        OCPdfImage* imagexobj = (OCPdfImage *)xobj;
        if (imagexobj.colorSpace != OCPdfColorSpace_DeviceRGB) {
            completion(nil);
            hasAlreadyCompleted = true;

        }

        [self getBitmapFromImage:imagexobj withCompletion:^(NSData *data) {
            NSData *uiImage = data;
            completion(uiImage);
            hasAlreadyCompleted = true;
        }];
    }
    
    if (!hasAlreadyCompleted) {
        completion(nil);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can your reproduce the issue? If yes, could you show the stackstrace when it fails? Did you enter an infinite loop with a specific parameter?

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem an infinite loop. It seems that somehow it's unable to return back the callback to the "parent call"

Comment: `completion` can be called multiple times? It's misleading, because usually, after a `completion` block, there is a "return", it's the end.

Comment: `completion` is not called in the completion block of the `getBitmapFromXObject` call.